# LinkedLists trying to call a class

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm very new to linked lists but currently I have a linkedlist of objects and was lost on how I would call's method another by using one of the objects in the linked list.

```
public Store() {
    products.add(new Product("Whiteboard Marker", 85, 1.50));
    products.add(new Product("Whiteboard Eraser", 45, 5.00));
    products.add(new Product("Black Pen", 100, 1.50));
    products.add(new Product("Red Pen", 100, 1.50));
    products.add(new Product("Blue Pen", 100, 1.50));

}
```

these are my current objects in the linkedlist.

I have a class called product with a function getName.

```
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}
```

So I was wondering how when calling the function getName, it would return "Black Pen"

thank you.

Comment: private String name, private int stock, private double price;

Comment: Are you familiar with pointers?

Comment: not very familiar with pointers, but ill look into them now

Comment: why exactly **"Black Pen"**??? that is neither the 1st nor the last element, do you need the one in the middle??? :)

Comment: Yes, I'll need to pick any of the 5 (more can be added by the user as well)

Comment: If I gave you a book and said "find a page with the words 'black pen'", how would you do it? You would look page-by-page, you would find it eventually and then you would tell me the page number.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I've gotten my answer down below (just cant accept it yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand it correctly, you have a list of product objects, which has a getter for name and you want to get the name of product, while its there in the Arraylist. According to this assumption i created a dummy `person` and `ArrayList` and calling the getter of product and printing it.

If you know the location of the object in the `ArrayList` then its easy to print it, just by giving the **index** of object in the `ArrayList`. otherwise if you know the some unique property of the person, then you can use `if` condition to filter on that property.

I've added both the case and included that in comment section.

```
   class Person {
    private String name;
    private String location;

    public Person(String name,String location) {
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Person> productList = new ArrayList<>();
        productList.add(new Person("Amit","india"));
        productList.add(new Person("A", "bangalore"));

        // case 1 :- when you know the location of person in LL.
        System.out.println(productList.get(0).getName());

        // case 2:- when you know some unique peroperty of person and filtering on base of this.
        for(Person product : productList){
            if(product.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("india")){
                System.out.println("name of person " + product.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}

Output :-
Amit
name of person Amit
```

Comment: Using `get(int)` is inefficient on `LinkedList`. If access by index is needed use an `ArrayList`.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch , i agree but i don't think this is the concern for OP and if you notice that in my code i used `ArrayList` only. Also modified linklist to arraylist in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, to get "Black Pen," you would write:

```
products.get(2).getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

To call a method of object stored in `LinkedList` you have to get this object from list. To take first element of linked list

```
products.getFirst().getName();
```

To take first element of linked list

```
products.getLast().getName();
```

Note that you can get elements from linked list only sequentially starting from first or from last.